# Any way to cache git source files?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

There is this great Cache task in Build pipelines.  It works great to cache nuget and npm packages (among others), but I don't see a corollary for the git sources.

Is there any way to do this, short of disabling the built in get sources and running our own git checkout as a task?  We have a relatively large repo that takes about 3 minutes to sync.  I'd like to reduce that if possible.  I've already tried using shallow fetch set to a depth of 1, and it hasn't appreciably changed the checkout time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure devops doesnot have this feature of Caching git source currently.

However, if you use self-hosted agent, the git source will be cached on your self-hosted agent machine by default(in the pipeline source code directory. eg. `C:\agent\_work\1\s` ). Next time when you run your pipeline, it will only checkout the changed files to your local machine.

So you can create a self-hosted agent to run your pipeline. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps to create self-hosted agent.

(If you want to clean the source code folder each time you run the pipeline. You can set the `clean` to `true` for [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) step.  clean option of checkout step will not work for Microsoft-hosted agent. Because Each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use.)

You can also click [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to submit a feature request(Click **Suggest a feature** and select **Azure Devops**. 
) to Microsoft development team. Hopefully they will consider adding this feature in the future.

Comment: Thanks @levi I suspected as much.I suppose i could disable syncing, then get the srouces myself in a script, and cache them that way